# How can I define an enum as CLI option with System.CommandLine.DragonFruit?

Tags: c#, system.commandline, system.commandline.dragonfruit

I'd like to define an enum as CLI option in C# [System.CommandLine.DragonFruit](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.CommandLine.DragonFruit). Is there "builtin" support for this use case? In detail I need an equivalent to Python's [`click`](https://pypi.org/project/click/) implementation of this:

```
@click.option('-m', '--mode', required=True, type=click.Choice(['SIM_MRM', 'SPECTRUM'], case_sensitive=True), help="The measurement mode.")
```

If I define the following in the C# console app

```
using System;

namespace EndDeviceAgent
{
    class Program
    {
        enum MeasurementMode : short
        {
            SIM_MRM,
            SPECTRUM
        }

        /// <param name="mode">The measurement mode.</param>
        static void Main(MeasurementMode mode)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Mode: {mode}");
        }
    }
}
```

I get `Mode: SIM_MRM` as output. However instead I'd like to get an exception cause the option is required and I don't want the default implied by the enum.

Comment: it seems to be an official dotnet package https://github.com/dotnet/command-line-api. _System.CommandLine.DragonFruit, Build command-line apps by convention with a strongly-typed Main method_

Comment: @thinwybk First and simple idea without knowing `System.CommandLine`: perhaps you can add a default `None = 0` enum value and check that at the beginning to throw the exception you ask for. `if ( mode == MeasurementMode.None ) throw new ...;`. Voted to reopen. Perhaps someone knows a better way.

Comment: @OlivierRogier Thanks. That worked. If you add the idiom as solution I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know `System.CommandLine`, but a simple way may be to add a default to the enum and to check mode at the beginning to throw an exception:

```
enum MeasurementMode
{
  NONE,
  SIM_MRM,
  SPECTRUM
}

static void Main(MeasurementMode mode)
{
  if ( mode == MeasurementMode.None ) 
    throw new ArgumentException("A mode value other than NONE must be provided.");

  Console.WriteLine($"Mode: {mode}");
}
```

Maybe a better solution exists, such as an attribute to apply the requirement, so that you can inspect [documentation or source code](https://github.com/dotnet/command-line-api) if you have time.

I removed the `short` keyword because it isn't needed, unless you have a good reason to use it (takes by default 4 bytes anyway on any x32/x64 system).

Answer (score 1):

Enums are now supported in System.Commandline

*"The values of enum types are bound by name, and the binding is case insensitive:"*
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/commandline/model-binding

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the answer from Olivier Rogier, using an initial `NONE` value was my first thought too.
I want to provide an alternative: using `Nullable` type. This could also be used with other simple value types like `int` to enforce that the user provides a value explicitly.

```
static void Main(Nullable<MeasurementMode> mode)
{
    if (!mode.HasValue) 
        throw new ArgumentException("A mode value must be provided.");

    Console.WriteLine($"Mode: {mode.Value}");
}
```

or equivalent but shorter

```
static void Main(T? mode)
{
    if (mode == null) 
        throw new ArgumentException("A mode value must be provided.");

    Console.WriteLine($"Mode: {mode.Value}");
}
```